# Extract mask from 3D RGB image using a 1D Boolean array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-slicing

I have a 3D image which is a numpy array of shape (1314, 489, 3) and looks as follows:

[image: RGB image]

Now I want to calculate the mean RGB color value of the mask (the cob without the black background). Calculating the RGB value for the whole image is easy:

```
print(np.mean(colormaskcutted, axis=(0, 1)))
>>[186.18434633  88.89164511  46.32022921]
```

But now I want this mean RGB color value only for the cob. I have a 1D boolean mask
array for the mask with this shape where one value corresponds to all of the 3 color channel values: (1314, 489)

I tried slicing the image array for the mask, as follows:

```
print(np.mean(colormaskcutted[boolean[:,:,0]], axis=(0, 1)))
>>124.57794089613752
```

But this returned only one value instead of 3 values for the RGB color.

How can I filter the 3D numpy image for a 1D boolean mask so that the mean RGB color calculation can be performed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is limited to computing the mean, you don't necessarily need to subset the image. You can simply do, e.g.

```py
np.sum(colormaskcutted*boolean[:,:,None], axis = (0,1))/np.sum(boolean)
```

P.S. I've played around with indexing, you can amend your original approach as follows:

```py
np.mean(colormaskcutted[boolean,:], axis = 0)
```

P.P.S. Can't resist some benchmarking. So, the summation approach takes `15.9s` (1000 iterations, dimensions like in the example, old computer); the advanced indexing approach is slightly longer, at `17.7s`. However, the summation can be optimized further. Using `count_nonzero` as per Mad Physicist suggestion marginally improves the time to `15.3s`. We can also use `tensordot` to skip creating a temporary array:

```
np.tensordot(colormaskcutted, boolean, axes = [[0,1], [0,1]])/np.count_nonzero(msk)
```

This cuts the time to `4.5s`.

Comment: The second solution is correct. I think you should remove the first.

Comment: @Mad Physicist They both give equivalent answers. The first one is slightly faster, and can be made still faster with tensordot (or einsum). The second one is more general.

Comment: Fair enough. How does using `np.count_nonzero` instead of `np.sum` affect the speed?

Comment: Thanks, I am happy with both options!

Comment: That's really neat.